# how small should be the code for inlining

Tags: c++, inline

Is it reasonable place the following code in inline function, or it is too big for inlining:

```
getPriority(const Data& data)
{
    Priority plidPriority = PRIORITY_STANDARD;

    if (data.isIPaddr)
    {
        Priority = PRIORITY_HIGHEST;
    }
    else if (data.plid == PROTO_HTTP || data.plid == PROTO_SIP || data.plid == PROTO_RTCP)
    {
        Priority = PRIORITY_PLID;
    }
    else if (data.port && data.port < 1024)
    {
        Priority = PRIORITY_ELEVATED;
    }

    return Priority;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you trust your compiler to make the correct decision on that? Unless you're doing this tens of millions of times per second, the difference is going to be negligible anyways.

Comment: Not sure it answers your question, but this article might be of interest to you: http://www.drdobbs.com/inline-redux/184403879

Comment: Worry about this when your profiler has shown this function is causing a problem.

Comment: It can make sense to inline a million lines of code, if they're called only from a function that itself is two lines.

Comment: @FredLarson good link. +1

Answer (score 1):

It is not reasonable to put any code for inlining just because you want to replace the function body inline to the point of function call, any modern day compiler will do so on its own.
You should use `inline` as a means of safely bypassing One definition Rule(ODR) and define functions in a header file rather than doing do for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How short the function should be for automatically in-lining ? Is
>      there any line-limit for that?

There is no hard limit (or more precisely yes, we can find upper limit on a given system but you won't find it specified anywhere). The compiler tries to predict what the advantages of this process given particular circumstances might be. If the compiler decides that inlining the function will make the code slower, or unacceptably larger, it will not inline it. Or, if it simply cannot because of a syntactical dependency, such as other code using a function pointer for callbacks, or exporting the function externally as in a dynamic/static code library. remember also that marking function `inline` is only expressing a wish, compiler is not obliged to do this.
In C, any function with internal linkage can be inlined, but a function with external linkage is subject to restriction.

> ```
> 2. Is there any way to know that a function is automatically in-lined ?
> ```

You can disassemble the binary and you will see if there is an call to a function or if it is **in line**.

[Do inline functions improve performance?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-and-perf.html)

[Inline Functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc07cplr243.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Main concern for for inlining is code bloating. So if your function is getting called at only one/few place(s) (and function is called many times so that the overhead is very large) a larger code can also be inlined (given that compiler inlines it) and it is okay to inline it. If you are calling a function at many places in the code then it can be a problem.

So it depends on how this function is called from the code which is not shown here.

Also it depends on the compiler if it inlines or not. If you think that inlining is very very necessary(which you can evaluate only after benchmarking) and the code is large you can go by increasing the limit by providing relevant compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Inlining is really just a suggestion to the compiler. For your case it would likely inline it already, or ignore the inline keyword completely